# Regexp help - is this possible at all with regexp?

Tags: regex

I'm still struggling with regexp, wondering if this is at all possible.

I need to parse variable names from expression, but I need to skip ones within string literals and ones after "dot".

so for expression like:
`'test' + (n + text.length)`

I would like to get only `n` and `text`.

I'm using `/([a-z_][a-z0-9_]*)/gi`

but it gives me `test,n,text,length`

Thanks for help:)

Comment: While **this example** is likely possible with regex, generalizing to all possible JavaScript expressions probably isn't. I would investigate JavaScript parsers instead.

Comment: If your input is not complicated, you may use [`/'[^']+'|(?:^|[^.])\b(\w+)/g`](https://regex101.com/r/pW0gY6/1) within a loop with `RegExp#exec()` (to grab the Group 1 value).

Comment: this does not have to be 100% accurate - I just wish to remove obvious false positives.

Comment: So, does https://jsfiddle.net/tmg2nLfp/ work for you?

Comment: something simple `/([a-z]+)\W*([a-z]+)(?=\.)/i` and grab $1 and $2

Comment: What engine are you using ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your input is not too complicated, here is a possible regex option:

```js
var re = /'[^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*'|"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"|(?:^|[^.])\b(\w+)/g; 
var str = '\'test\\\' this\' + "Missing \\\"here\\\"" + (n + text.length)';
document.body.innerHTML = "Testing string: <b>" + str + "</b><br/>";
var res = [];
while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
    if (m[1]) { res.push(m[1]); }
}
document.body.innerHTML += JSON.stringify(res, 0, 4);
```

The regex details:

- `'[^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*'` - single quoted string literals (supporting escaped sequences)
- `|` - or
- `"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"` - double quoted string literals (supporting escaped sequences)
- `|` - or
- `(?:^|[^.])\b(\w+)` - 1+ word characters that are either right at the string start or after a non-dot and preceded with a word boundary (placed inside Group 1)

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xA9tG8/1).

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Please also consider upvoting if my answer proved helpful to you (see [How to upvote on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow)).